# Keras is not working on splitted dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, regression, keras-layer

**Here is the code:**

[image: Code]

**I get the following error:**

[image: Error]

**Snapshot of the dataset:**

[image: Snapshot]

Please suggest me what should I do now to get rid of the error

Comment: You should copy your code in line in your post and not link to outside images.

Comment: Actually, I am new on this platform, so I found it little difficult in posting codes here but will keep that in mind and from next time I will write my codes in line :)

Comment: Use this to learn how to format things here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: So, do you want 5 input features and one output feature? Or is it something else?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the resource :)  and yes I want 5 input features and 1 output feature

Comment: After fitting the splitted data I got the error

Comment: Your `Y` must then be shaped `(any,1)`, but you made it `(any,5) `.

Comment: Didn't get you mate..should I have to change the value of Y at line no. 24?

Comment: Got my error resolved :) thanks guys

Comment: The sequence of Y_train and X_test was the reason for getting the error...changing the sequence resolved it :)